# Reading in integers from an input file and writing to an output file using arrays in Java

Tags: java, arrays

Okay, so I'm not totally sure I'm using arrays correctly or not, but here goes. I have a homework assignment and I'm trying to read from an input file and write to an output file using arrays. I have to show the high temperatures and low temperatures and find the averages for each day of the week. The problem I'm having right now is that nothing is being written to the output file.
Here is what I have so far.

```
package dowtemps;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class DOWTemps
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int index = 0;
        int temp = 0;
        int dow = 0;
        int[] lowTempArray = new int[8];
        int[] highTempArray = new int[8];
        int[] countArray = new int[8];
        int[] totalArray = new int[8];

        InputFile in = new InputFile("input.txt");
        OutputFile out = new OutputFile("output.txt");

        System.out.println("DOW Temperature Started. Please Wait....");

        for (index = 0; index < 8; index++)
        {
            lowTempArray[index] = 999;
            highTempArray[index] = -999;
            countArray[index] = 0;
            totalArray[index] = 0;
            dow++;
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(lowTempArray));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(highTempArray));

        while (!in.eof())
        {
            //read in records
            dow = in.readInt();
            temp = in.readInt();
            //load arrays
            lowTempArray[dow] = temp;
            highTempArray[dow] = temp;

            if (temp > highTempArray[dow])
            {
                highTempArray[dow] = temp;
            }
            else
            {
                lowTempArray[dow] = temp;
            }

            totalArray[dow] = totalArray[dow] + temp;
            countArray[dow]++;
            //write records

            out.writeInt(dow);
            out.writeInt(lowTempArray[dow]);
            out.writeInt(highTempArray[dow]);
            out.writeInt(totalArray[dow]);
            out.writeInt(countArray[dow]);
            out.writeInt((totalArray[dow] / (countArray[dow])));
            out.writeEOL();
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(lowTempArray));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(highTempArray));
        System.out.println("DOW Temperature Completed Successfully.");
        out.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't look like InputFile or OutputFile are standard Java objects. Are those defined by other files in your project?

Comment: I suspect you are writing the data but you are not looking for the file in the right place, or re-opening it.  Otherwise, if there is a bug it is in the class `OutputFile`  Are you sure the `while` loop is lopping? What do you see when you step through your code in your debugger?

Comment: I think I'll check my logic... it was writing just fine when I started... so maybe it's my logic...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can change InputFile and OutFile for this:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("output.txt", "UTF-8");
```

I did a little changes on your code, now it read and print.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DOWTemps
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, UnsupportedEncodingException
    {
        int index = 0;
        int temp = 0;
        int dow = 0;
        int[] lowTempArray = new int[8];
        int[] highTempArray = new int[8];
        int[] countArray = new int[8];
        int[] totalArray = new int[8];

        Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("output.txt", "UTF-8");
        System.out.println("DOW Temperature Started. Please Wait....");

        for (index = 0; index < 8; index++)
        {
            lowTempArray[index] = 999;
            highTempArray[index] = -999;
            countArray[index] = 0;
            totalArray[index] = 0;
            dow++;
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(lowTempArray));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(highTempArray));

        while (in.hasNextLine())
        {
            //read in records
            dow = in.nextInt();
            temp = in.nextInt();
            //load arrays
            lowTempArray[dow] = temp;
            highTempArray[dow] = temp;

            if (temp > highTempArray[dow])
            {
                highTempArray[dow] = temp;
            }
            else
            {
                lowTempArray[dow] = temp;
            }

            totalArray[dow] = totalArray[dow] + temp;
            countArray[dow]++;
            //write records

            out.println(dow);
            out.println(lowTempArray[dow]);
            out.println(highTempArray[dow]);
            out.println(totalArray[dow]);
            out.println(countArray[dow]);
            out.println((totalArray[dow] / (countArray[dow])));
            out.println();
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(lowTempArray));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(highTempArray));
        System.out.println("DOW Temperature Completed Successfully.");
        out.close();
    }
}
```

Just check the logic of your program if its what you need